# HTML5 canvas painting rectangle on mouse click

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have a canvas which loads in a selected image. The canvas should display 2 6x6 rectangles where the user clicks. On the first click, the rectangle should be red, the second click it should be blue on the third click, it resets (deletes both first rectangles) and so on..
This works fine (see example here: http://jsfiddle.net/8HSGG/)

My problem is when I reload an image, the rectangles start messing up (i.e. colors come in different order or don't show up at all).

I have two variables in the Javascript: topLeft and bottomRight which are both null whenever an image is loaded in, then a check based on those and paint accordingly.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: Please always include the relevant code within your question.  External links are great but if they cease to exist, your question should still be useful to others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're adding `click` and `mouseover` event listeners to the canvas every time you're "handling" the image.  Thus, I would suspect you're getting code that gets invoked multiple times.

Comment: is there anyway to remove all event listeners from the canvas on a new image load?

Comment: AFAIK, if you are explicitly using the DOM methods to handle adding event listeners *without saving what the event listeners are*, what you request is impossible.  BTW, event listeners would not be identified by the same function block but likely by *closure*; at least that's what my tests would appear to indicate.  The simplest solution is probably to set the event handlers up once and forget, and then keep the canvas hidden until an image is loaded.

Comment: Is it possible I have the canvas inside a div and have the div reloaded on each image load?

Comment: You mean replace the contents of the div with a new canvas?  There's nothing stopping you.